# Can content in DIVs be sorted?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to sort DIVs, based on `value` from the form the DIV contains?

Hare is the HTML, to better get a visual idea how the HTML looks like

http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/gtYBE/1/

Here is the HTML simplified to illustrate the problem:

```
<div id="contentEdit">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cellHeader"> ID    </div>
    <div class="cellHeader"> Title </div>
  </div>

  <div id="content">

    <div id="127">
      <form action="" method="post">
    <div class="row">
          <!-- ----- cell one -----              -------------------------- cell two ----------------------- -->
      <div class="cell"> 127 </div>   <div class="cell"> <input name="title" value="dfg" type="text" /> </div>
    </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <!-- next row -->

    <div id="27">
      <form action="" method="post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell"> 27 </div>   <div class="cell"> <input name="title" value="afg" type="text" /> </div>
    </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

What I would like is to be able to click on a button to sort each row i.e. `<div id="127">` and `<div id="27">` based on the content of `<div class="cell"> 127 </div>`, (the content is here 127).

Another button should sort the rows based on form `value`.

Is that possible?

Comment: Any reason to not sort on the id of the div?

Comment: I'd rather use table for this kind of stuff.  You can take a look here: http://tablesorter.com/docs/ or here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#items or you can use Google Visualization API - there are all sort of sortable options - http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/examples.html

Comment: @Ryan Olds : Good idea. That would be perfect =) Still I don't know to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is is an example of sorting by the id: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanrolds/CuJ9T/

The above example doesn't require jQuery. It's not a drop in solution for your exact problem but it should give a very good idea how to solve your current problem.

Comment: When I click Run, it doesn't output anything in the Result field.

Comment: Look at the console output. The children of the container is sorted. I will style the output so you see something in the right.

Comment: Try it now. On the right you should see that the divs are in order.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JQuery solution.  There are several other javascript sorting libararies out there to choose from.

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: I did look at that one. To me it seams it only works on `<table>`'s ?

Comment: I don't think there is any library out there that is made to do that with just divs yet, however it is certainly possible.  The other option is if your using a SQL server with your data is to just do an ajax call and have your SQL server do the sorting for you.  Although it's always nice to let the client do the work for you.  Good luck to you, if you find a solution make sure to post back.  I would like to see this also.